# Sigma.js graph animate(transition effect) color of nodes and edges?

Tags: graph, webgl, sigma.js

I want to have a smooth color transition effect when hovering node (duration 2s for example) using sigma.js, but I don't see any example/docs of how to do this.

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/main/examples/use-reducers

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You have to add the code to the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change.

Comment: By playing with a timer and the node reducer, I think it's possible but it's not easy.
What I see on the example is a flicker effect when I fastly navigate on the graph with my mouse. 
This can be avoid by adding a debounce on hover node.